# How do I pass a textfile into a 2D array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, text-files, csv

I am required to pass a textfile that contains comma separated integers into a 2D array in c++.
eg if the textfile looks like:

```
2,3,56,4
3,5,7,1
0,23,9,87
2,4,5,2
```

I need to put this into a 2D array so that I may later perform calculations (which I do know how to do).
I have the following code, but I am struggling very much. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    const int row =4;
    const int col =4;
    int array[row][col];
    int r =0;
    int c =0;

    ifstream inputfile("numbers.txt");
    if (!inputfile.is_open())
    {
        cout<<"error"<<endl;
    }
    string line,num;
    int number;
    while(get line(inputfile,line))
    {
        string stream ss(line);
        getline(ss,num,',');
        number = stoi(num);

        for (int r=0; r<row;r++)
        {
            for (int c=0; c<col; c++)
            {
                array[row][col] =number;
            }
        }


        inputfile.close();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ csv 2d array".  There are already a plethora of examples on the internet to read a Comma Separated File (csv).  Check this out [CSV examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+read+csv+2d+array&oq=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+read+csv+2d+array&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.11118j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: In the first place, "I'm struggling so much" is not helpful, as we don't know exactly what part of the project you're struggling with. The Code itself? An Algorithm? Compiling? Text file not being located? In either case, I formatted your code, and you can see according to what you posted, you are returning INSIDE the while loop. Is this intended?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example:

```
static const int MAX_ROWS = 4;
static const int MAX_COLUMNS] = 4;
int matrix[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS];
//...
for (int row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; ++ row)
{
    std::string row_text;
    std::getline(inputfile, row_text);
    std::istringstream row_stream(row_text);
    for (int column = 0; column < MAX_COLUMNS; ++column)
    {
       int number;
       char delimiter;
       row_stream >> number >> delimiter;
       matrix[row][column] = number;
    }
}
```

The above assumes that the text file contains the exact quantity of numbers.

Since the separators differ at the end of a line, each line is read as a string, then use `std::istringstream` to treat the stream as a file.